# Bone constraint Limit Rotation does nothing (v3.2.1)

Tags: constraints

I have a bone with a Limit Rotation constraint on it, and it appears to be completely ineffective.

There are plenty of tutorials covering adding a constraint and mine simply isn't working.
Here is one such tutorial for reference - https://youtu.be/y6ECmeANUSw

So am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is object constraints:

[image]

And this is bone constraints:

[image]

So that you have added object constraint, but move bone, not object itself.

Pay attention to that you have 2 separate armatures instead of 2 bones in one armature. Consider joining them into one armature.

[image]

Comment: Ooh that's sneaky... I did not realise there was a separate set of constraints for objects. I figured all constraints were for the bones. I can make it work now, thank you!